# Issue with Twilio Call from URL in WebView on MacOS Catalyst

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, wkwebview, mac-catalyst

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently facing a challenge with Twilio call functionality in a WebView on MacOS Catalyst. The issue is specific to Twilio calls initiated from a URL within the WebView. Strangely, the functionality works flawlessly in the iPhone simulator, but on MacOS Catalyst, the calls from URL seem to be encountering problems.

```
@IBOutlet var WKWebView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    

    permissionForRecording()
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


func permissionForRecording() {
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
        try session.setActive(true)

        if session.responds(to: #selector(AVAudioSession.requestRecordPermission(_:))) {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission { [weak self] (granted: Bool) -> Void in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                if granted {
                    print("granted")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.setupWKWebView()
                    }
                } else {
                    print("not granted")
                    // Handle case when permission is not granted
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error setting up AVAudioSession: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func setupWKWebView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let preferences = WKWebpagePreferences()
    preferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true // Enable JavaScript
    webConfiguration.defaultWebpagePreferences = preferences

    // Use the existing WKWebView outlet
    WKWebView.isOpaque = false
    WKWebView.navigationDelegate = self
    WKWebView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

    let url = URL(string: "")
    let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
    WKWebView.load(requestObj)
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. "The calls from URL seem to be encountering problems", what problems?